# Update objects from two modules with same attribute in DOORS

Tags: requirements, ibm-doors, ibm-rational, requirements-management

I have one module with objects that have the attribute *customer ID*.
I have new module, with updated data, which was an import from PDF to DOORS using ReqMan.

Now I want to update the first module with data from the new module. The *customer ID* attribute is equal in both modules, but I cannot find a way in DOORS to do a sort of VLOOKUP to look for the *customer ID* and update the *Object Text* on the base module.

Preferably I would like to do it without DXL.

Answer (score 1):

(modify the following instructions as needed - I describe my favorite settings here)

Use spreadsheet import and export, preferably Tab separated.
For export, create a view which does NOT contain Absolute Number nor the main column, but all the data you want to modify plus customer ID. Ensure that the labels of the columns are identical to the attribute names.

In the generated text file, you can change the attributes for existing rows and you can add new rows with customer IDs that do not yet exist in the module. Make sure that the first line contains the attribute names.

After you updated your text file, open the module and choose File -> Import -> Spreadsheet with the following settings :

- Import to attributes: by column labes
- Import options: Update existing objects
- Update: All Objects
- Data separator: Tab
- Input file: the full path to your .tsv file
- Advanced: check that the columns in the first row correspond to your attribute names
- set the correct encoding
- press Import
- there should be no question  "create new attribute?"
- In the dialog "Select key", select "customer ID" as the "column/attribute that uniquely identifies the objects".
- press "Select"
- check the result, save the module only if everything looks correct.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the answer.
The thing is that I want to update the main column (object text).

Comment: Main column is not really an attribute. In the main column you see a) "Object Heading", if it is filled, together with a chapter number and / or b) "Object Text", if it is filled.  For the import, don't show the main column but the attributes "Object Heading" and "Object Text" in separate columns

Answer (score 0):

```
Object ob, ob1
Module m = current // First module

string s="/Training Car Project/Stakeholder Requirements" //Give full path of your second module

Module mod=read(s,false)

for ob in m do
{
for ob1 in mod do
{
if((ob."customer ID""" = ob1."customer ID""") && (ob."Object Text""" != ob1."Object Text"""))
{
ob."Object Text""" = ob1."Object Text"""
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Peetman, please test the script and let me know. It should work